# Python 2.7 Value Error : need more than 2 values to unpack

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, unpack

I have Python 2.7 Win 32 and have installed Matplotlib, Numpy, PyParsing, Dateutil. In IDLE I place in the code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

def graphRawFX () :
    date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt,unpack=True,('GPBUSD1d.txt')
    delimiter=',',
    converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') }
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)

    ax1.plot(date,bid)
    ax1.plot(date,ask)

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are three variable but only two values given

```
date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt,unpack=True,('GPBUSD1d.txt')
```

you probably need to change that line to :

```
date=mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
bid,ask = np.loadtxt,unpack=True,('GPBUSD1d.txt')
```

Comment: What if I want to get date? What happened now was that this appeared NameError: global name 'date' is not defined

Comment: @BenthePyro you defined three variables ie `date,bid,ask` and only assigned two. so you must assign the 3rd variable too. you must define `date= <value for date>`

Comment: Can't assign literal? This is getting really frustrating.

Comment: @BenthePyro try `date=mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')`

Comment: When I run I type in rawGraphFX(). Pressing enter I get ValueError: Unrecognized character G in format string. Any ideas would be great as I'm searching for a solution with no luck.

Comment: I cannot chat because I need more rep.